# Angular MatSort: change default ascending method to ignore 0

Tags: angular, sorting

Consider an Angular mat-table with items and price of items, like so (Fruit and Price are headers):

```
Fruit      Price
Banana     0
Apple      1
Pear       2
```

Both of these headers are mat-sort-headers, but when clicking on "Price" to sort the items by Price, I would like them listed in ascending order, **ignoring 0 and putting all 0 value at the end of the list, like so:**

```
Fruit      Price
Apple      1
Pear       2
Banana     0
```

Ideally, when sorting by descending order, 0 values would still be put at the very end, like so.

```
Fruit      Price
Pear       2
Apple      1
Banana     0
```

Currently, Angular only offers the ascending order [0, 1, 2]. How can I override the default ascending order with my own method?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `matSortChange` event to change the datasource

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acrzyv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsort-overview-example.ts

**HTML**

```
<table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
  <tr>
    <th mat-sort-header="name">Name</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="price">Price</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let fruit of sortedData">
    <td>{{fruit.name}}</td>
    <td>{{fruit.price}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Component**

```
fruits = [
    {name: 'Banana', price: 0 },
    {name: 'Apple', price: 0 },
    {name: 'Orange', price: 2 },
    {name: 'Tomato', price: 1 },
  ];

  sortedData: any[];

  constructor() {
    this.sortedData = this.fruits.slice();
  }

  sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.fruits.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      this.sortedData = data;
      return;
    }

    this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
      if (b.price === 0) return -1;
      return compare(a.price, b.price, isAsc);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Stavm. I should have mentioned that I also work with a DataSource rather than set rows so I can't use `let fruit of sortedData`,

Is there a way to update the dataSource after the data has been sorted, something like this maybe?
`this.dataSource.data = this.sortedData;`

Comment: this doesn't work with multiple fruits: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acrzyv-l3fbjh?file=src/app/sort-overview-example.ts @Stavm